# What happens when a jQuery selector wasn't found?

Tags: jquery

If I pass one `selector` as a `parameter` to a function.

```
// selector is an object
function(selector) {

  selector.trigger('eventHere');
}
```

Obviously, the `event` will never fire if the `selector` that was passed in didn't have this `event`, but should I do some condition checking before triggering the event? I mean:

```
// selector is an object
if(selector === 'matched'){
  // then fire the event
}
else{
  // do nothing
}
```

or just leave it...?

Comment: jQuery selectors are plain strings (e.g. `"div.main h2"`) so I guess you're giving that name to another concept. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nice thing about jQuery is that it will not throw an exception or cause an error if the selector doesn't match. So you needn't do anything extra; this is a safe operation:

```
// selector **must** be a jQuery object
// the assumption here is that you've already done 
// var selector = $('selectorString'); elsewhere
// and have invoked this function with selector
function(selector){
  selector.trigger('eventHere');
}
```

Do note however that you must ensure that `selector` is a jQuery object! Otherwise, you could get an error indicating that `trigger` is not a function.

**Edit**

Adam Terlson notes in the comments "*it can be worth testing if a jquery object is null or has length of 0 before execution of a function against it. Just because it won't throw an error doesn't mean that performance can't be gained by not executing it in the first place (jQuery still tries).*"

There's also a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-check-for-null-selector-or-just-perform-method2) test that shows that there is a discernable difference in the ops/sec for each technique (it's not time! That threw me off at first) - checking for a `null`/`0`-length jQuery object before calling the function vs. simply invoking the function.

Comment: As a footnote to your great suggestion, it can be worth testing if a jquery object is null or has length of 0 before execution of a function against it.  Just because it won't throw an error doesn't mean that performance can't be gained by not executing it in the first place (jQuery still tries).

Comment: @Adam That sounds like a good idea - but I would imagine that finding matches for a selector string would be the most expensive operation for jQuery. Invoking a function on elements, once found, should be relatively inexpensive. Thoughts? References/numbers showing otherwise? I'd be interested in knowing if adding the `if(selector)` to the code above would have a positive impact.

Comment: @NoGood - The impact is _relatively_ small compared to some performance issues, but worth doing.  Here's a jsperf test to prove it: http://jsperf.com/jquery-check-for-null-selector-or-just-perform-method2  I see a 19% improvement gain by testing for a result first in Chrome.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for showing that - definitely worth keeping in mind. Do you suppose it's the error handling overhead that causes the slowdown?

Comment: Regarding your edit, to be fair, I didn't create the jsperf test, merely dug it up.  As for the why, it's simply that jQuery does a lot of stuff regardless of length.  Taking the jsperf's example of `remove()`, look at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js and search for `remove: function` to find the definition.  You'll see it's testing for various types, collections, doing event unbinding, etc.  It's not due to error handling--in fact, only in rare cases does jQuery actually need to use try/catch blocks.

Comment: Thanks Adam, this was definitely very instructive!

Comment: Soon you'll need a new username.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery always returns an array of elements, even if the selector returned no elements at all, it will contain an empty array.

You can still execute any function on that empty array without jQuery throwing an error, so there is no need to check if the returned elements exist.

If the element has no such event to trigger, yet you try to trigger it, nothing will happen, no exception will get thrown, again ; no need to check.

please also note, that if you insist on passing a selector to your object, you still need to fetch objects using the selector before you can do anything with them.

```
function myTriggerFunction(selector)
{
  var elements = $(selector);
  elements.trigger('eventHere');
}

myTriggerFunction('.WeWillBeTriggered');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger the event..

But the *selector* variable should actually be a jQuery object (*with the syntax you use*).

Answer (score 1):

If the creation of the jQuery object didn't match any elements, it will still be a jQuery object but with zero elements inside. Most methods that you perform on a jQuery object can handle any number of elements, including zero, so if you just want to do nothing you don't have to do any checking.

It's only if you want to do something special when the collection is empty that you have to check for it, and you do that by checking the `length` property:

```
function(selection){
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    selection.trigger('eventHere');
  } else {
    // do something else because the selection was empty
  }
}
```

Note that a "selector" is the string that you use to specify what elements to put in a jQuery object, like the string `#main` in the code `$('#main')`, so calling a jQuery object "selector" can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the event will be triggered only for a certain element type, you can check that before triggering the event.

```
if (selector.is("type of element")) {
   //then fire event
}
```

or, if you want to check it by tag name

```
if (selector.get(0).tagName=="tag name") {
   //then fire event
}
```

Comment: isn't the whole point of jquery's selectors that you already know this beforehand?

Comment: As per OP, assumption is that the function will be called even for selectors (elements) that doesn't support the registered event.

Comment: in that case, `selector.is("type of element")` will always return false in your example, and should be iterated.