# jquery trigger change event on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to trigger change event on a checkbox using javascript/jquery?

Something like this (I run triggerChange on click of a button):

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="chk"/>Label for chk</label>

<script>
function triggerChange(){
    $("#chk").trigger("change");
}
</script>
```

When I run the above code I get this error: "**trigger is not a function**".

Comment: Of course it is possible. Most probably you've forgotten to include jQuery.

Comment: I think you would be interested by this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159214/why-does-dynamically-changing-a-checkbox-not-trigger-a-form-change-event

Don't forget to get placed on a $(document).ready context !

Comment: It sounds like `$` returns something which is not a jQuery object. Which means `$` might not be jQuery? Also note that triggering the change event will only run the change event handlers, it will not change the state of the checkbox.

Comment: Okay but how do you want it to be triggerred like change or click.

Comment: I'm not interested in click event. I have my reasons do not use the click. I want to trigger the change event without clicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That `trigger is not a function` error message indicates something else is at play. According to this SO question:

[What happens when a jQuery selector wasn't found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705067/what-happen-when-the-selector-didnt-find-in-jquery)

`no.good.at.coding` says:

> Do note however that you must ensure that selector is a jQuery object!
>   Otherwise, you could get an error indicating that "trigger is not a
>   function".

It's likely that you have forgotten jQuery?

---

As for your implementation, you should be fine the way you are using it. But `trigger` should be used to trigger event methods on elements that have already been attached via jQuery. Check out my demo:

**Fiddle:**
With click event: http://jsfiddle.net/fS4R5/1/
Without click event: http://jsfiddle.net/fS4R5/2/

**HTML:**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="chk"/>Label for chk</label>
```

**JS:**

```
function triggerChange(){
    $("#chk").trigger("change");
}

$("#chk").change(function() {
   alert("triggered!"); 
});

triggerChange();
```

Comment: If not attached, the browser won't raise *"trigger is not a function"* exception. jQuery is tuned for it.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer with details regarding the exception.

Comment: I'm not interested in click event. I have my reasons do not use the click. I want to trigger the change event without clicking the checkbox.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle working example that triggers that event without click?

Answer (score 7):

Be sure that Input of Type checkbox is enabled, in case is disabled trigger will not fire event

```
//fire event 
$('#ceckBoxId').click();
$('#ceckBoxId').trigger('click');
```

or change checkbox `checked` val

```
$('#ceckBoxId').prop('checked', true);
$('#ceckBoxId').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: my control was disabled, so it was not working. Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

In jQuery, you can usually trigger an event by calling it's eventhandler method withoud any function parameters.

For example a click handler can be assigned as such:

`$('#mything').click(function(e){dostuff});`

the click event in itself can be triggered by simply running:
`$('#mything').click();`

I suspect this can be done for every existing event in jQuery.

Comment: You can also call it with `.trigger("click")`. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I'm not interested in click event. I have my reasons do not use the click. I want to trigger the change event without clicking the checkbox.

Comment: Well, 'click' was only an example. You might as well replace it with the function 'change'. For reference: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: could you put an example. It will be better

Answer (score 2):

I think the preferred method since 1.9.1 is 'on'. Specially if you use dynamically added checkboxes.

Say you have a div with id='divCOntent' and on it is a checkbox with id='cballaut', you could do this

```
$('#divcontent').on('click', '#cballaut', function (e) {
                    alert(this.checked);
                });
```

Comment: That hardly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

use prop method.

```
$('#myCheck').prop('checked', true);
$('#myCheck').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: This won't trigger a change event.